# Cannot Connect Magento with SSL/TLS Error

Tags: ssl

There was an error downloading 'https://103.21.128.85/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl'. The request was aborted:

> Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://103.21.128.85/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl'.

> Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority
>   '103.21.128.85'.

The request was aborted:

> Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Please assist in reported issue as already hanging about 1 month, still cannot resolve even after trying so many methods?

Thanks.